# Replace string in a element with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using a jQuery script to replace text in an element. Now I need to do this with plain Javascript.

How do I do that?

This is the script I'm currently using:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $( ".tp-caption.black:contains('.000000')" ).text('.1111111');
});
```

Comment: Do you want to have the exact same match? `:contains` is a jQuery selector and would need to replaced with vanilla js as well.

Comment: Yeah, the string will always have .000000 in it, and I want to replace that specific part of the string.

Comment: Nothing so far since Im unsure where to start. @Praveen Kumar

Comment: Have you even looked on google dude? This is a pretty simple thing to do in JS... seems like more effort to post a question on SO?

Answer (score 3):

Using a small polyfill like this:

```
function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
```

You can do something like:

```
// Get all the elements.
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("tp-caption");
// Iterate each.
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    // Check if the text is found.
    if (elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(".000000") != -1 && hasClass(elements[i], "black"))
        // Replace the contents.
        elements[i].innerHTML = '.1111111';
}
```

This replaces the whole string. If you wanna replace only that part, then use this:

```
// Get all the elements.
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("tp-caption");
// Iterate each.
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    // Check if the text is found.
    if (elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(".000000") != -1 && hasClass(elements[i], "black"))
        // Replace the contents.
        elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace('.000000', '.1111111');
}
```

Gosh, you can even do this way:

```
// Get all the elements.
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("tp-caption black");
// Iterate each.
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    // Check if the text is found.
    if (elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(".000000") > -1)
        // Replace the contents.
        elements[i].innerHTML = '.1111111';
}

// Get all the elements.
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("tp-caption black");
// Iterate each.
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    // Check if the text is found.
    if (elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(".000000") > -1)
        // Replace the contents.
        elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace('.000000', '.1111111');
}
```

And for modern browsers, you can simply use:

```
// Get all the elements.
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".tp-caption.black");
// Iterate each.
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    // Check if the text is found.
    if (elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(".000000") != -1)
        // Replace the contents.
        elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace('.000000', '.1111111');
}
```

Comment: You can also use elements[i].textContent = '.1111111';

Comment: `tp-caption.black` will not work in `getElementsByClassName`, you would have to `querySelectorAll` with a `.` or use spaces

Comment: There is no consistency in `textContent` vs `innerText`. That's why I didn't use that!

Comment: what is `substr` ? and maybe you want check `indexOf("xx") > -1`

Comment: You don't need to check if its there in order to replace it, the replace will do that for you. Also `getElementsByClassName` takes the sytax `(classOne ClassTwo)` not `(classOne.classTwo)`

Comment: `str.indexOf` will never return `false`, the not found value is `-1`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Do you even Javascript?! Too many edits and flaws in your answer

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne I do! `;)`

Comment: @Hacketo `> -1` and `!= -1` both mean the same in this context right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes but you used `!== false`, that will never be true

Comment: Which he's now changed!

Comment: This is far too complex for what he is doing!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting the whole thing in Vanilla JS its like this:

```
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('tp-caption black');
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    var t = arr[i].innerHTML;
    t = t.replace('.000000', '.111111');

    arr[i].innerHTML = t;
}
```

If you're wanting just the replace bit in Vanilla JS its like this:

```
var t = $('.tp-caption.black').text();
$('.tp-caption.black').text(t.replace('.000000', '.111111'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments give you an indication of what the *vanilla* (sort of) matches up to from the *jQuery*

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () { // $('document').ready(function () {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('.tp-caption.black'), // $( ".tp-caption.black
        function (e) {
            if (e.textContent.indexOf('.000000') !== -1) // :contains('.000000')" )
                e.textContent = '.1111111'; // .text('.1111111');
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar works since IE9 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @PraveenKumar IE6 and IE5? `:P`

Comment: IE 8 is still widely used unfortunately

Comment: @PaulS. I will commit suicide!

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne IE 9 works on _Vista SP2_, supporting IE 8 is supporting XP, which is supporting an OS past it's end-of-life

Comment: However it is still widely used whether the OS is out of date or not `:S`